# Redefining the Data Link between a MS Access file and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I have a pretty standard database sitting on SQL Server. To manage the data (instead of creating a solution using an IDE) I've linked to the database using MS-Access (4 users as a start. I'm testing a concept and a full solution can be developed once there's enough data).

*MS-Access > New file > Project using exiting data...
*Specify SQL Server server
*Create forms and so forth.  Data now available/editable in Access.

Considering the sql database isn't always going to be running on my laptop, the Access file's server reference will have to change.

How do you modify/redefine the datalink between the Access file and the SQL server?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Connection to bring up the data source selection window.